# Spy for $rootScope.$broadcast is not working when everything else is?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I have a keyboard shortcut directive that I'm trying to test. It's purpose is to trigger `$rootScope.$broadcast()` with the event data. In the application it works without any issue but I can't get this darn test to pass as thoroughly as I would like.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.common')
        .directive('keyboardShortcuts', keyboardShortcuts);

    // @ngInject
    function keyboardShortcuts($document, $rootScope){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link
        }

        function link(scope, el, attrs){
            $document.bind('keypress', event => {
                console.log('detected keypress');
                $rootScope.$broadcast('keyboardShortcut', event);

                scope.$digest(); // seems to make no difference
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

For the unit test, I've added a `$scope.$on` handler to show that the broadcast is actually being made and listened to, but for some reason the spy isn't doing it's job.

```
describe('KeyboardShortcuts Directive', function(){
    'use strict';

    let $element;
    let $scope;
    let vm;
    let $document;
    let $rootScope;

    const mockKeyboardEvent = {
        type: 'keypress',
        bubbles: true,
        altKey: false,
        ctrlKey: false,
        shiftKey: false,
        which: 106
    }

    beforeEach(module('app.common'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $compile, _$document_){
        $element = angular.element('<div keyboard-shortcuts></div>');
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $document = _$document_;

        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $compile($element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();

        spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast');
    }));

    ////////////

    it('should broadcast when a key is pressed', function(){
        $scope.$on('keyboardShortcut', (event, data) => {
            console.log('wtf!?');
            expect(data.which).toBe(106);
        });

        $document.triggerHandler(mockKeyboardEvent);

        $scope.$digest(); // seems to make no difference

        expect($rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

And here is the console output. You can see that the code appears to be working otherwise.

```
[15:33:57] Starting 'build:common:js'...
[15:33:58] Finished 'build:common:js' after 227 ms
[15:33:58] Starting 'test:common'...
20 09 2016 15:33:58.250:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
20 09 2016 15:33:58.250:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
20 09 2016 15:33:58.253:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
20 09 2016 15:33:58.797:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#37Fv2zndO5Z6XAZ8AAAg with id 3035140
..
LOG: 'detected keypress'
LOG: 'wtf!?'
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) KeyboardShortcuts Directive should broadcast when a key is pressed FAILED
    Expected spy $broadcast to have been called.
```

In the past, when unit testing controllers, I was having trouble like this as well. I was trying to spy on methods that were run in the `activate()` method which was run immediately (Papa style), I was able to get my spies to work by putting the `spyOn(...)` method **above** where the controller was instantiated. In this case, I tried putting my `spyOn` in all sorts of places within that 'beforeEach' and nothing has seemed to make a difference.

I also tried the obvious solution of putting the `expect..broadcast..beenCalled()` stuff inside of the `$on` handler, but that didn't work either, even though that assertion passes and is total proof that ***a*** broadcast was made.

I sort of have a feeling that the $rootScope being spied on isn't the same $rootScope that is being injected and working otherwise, but I don't know how that can be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper variable naming is important.

This

```
$rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
```

is one of wide-spread mistakes in Angular unit tests.

The problem is that a thing that was called `$rootScope` is just child scope, not root scope. As it appears, it is easy to forget this, so

```
spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast');
```

stubs `$broadcast` method on some scope.

It should be

```
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

And

```
    $scope.$digest(); // seems to make no difference
```

shouldn't be there because jQuery/jqLite events aren't tied to digest cycles.

Comment: Changing `$rootScope = _$rootScope_.new()` seems to have done the trick. I had some issues in another test with not doing it that way, so that's why I kept the pattern. It seems I'll have to go check those tests again. Thank you!